# You do not have permission to access this document ASP.NET MVC 3 on Plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, publishing, plesk

After i upload my website on remote host i got following error:

> **403 Forbidden** 
>   You do not have permission to access this document

My website is an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application on Plesk 9.5.4 panel.

[update]

First of all, i'm sorry for my bad question!

I uploaded `bin`, `Views`, `Content`, `Scripts`, `web.config` and `Global.asax` file on `httpdocs` directory on host, but after refreshing the page i got 403 error. I also upload `System.Web.Mvc.dll` and `EntityFramework.dll` beside of my `MicroCatalog.dll` file in `bin` folder.

**Is there any kind of configuration on Plesk or should I write any code to fix this problem?**

My default controller is `Home` and default action is `Index` as described on global.asax.cs file:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute("Signout", "Account/LogOff/");

    }
```

[/update]

Comment: whats your default controller name ?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. While you're here, do you have a programming question?

Comment: @Widor : Is there a convenience website in stackexchange.com to ask this kind of questions?

Comment: @Jalal - my point is you haven't _asked_ a question...

Comment: @JalalAmini you didnt ask a question , also you didnt say any details for what you did , as I answered Plesk does not redirect you to your home page , please tell us whats your home controller so the people here can help you

Comment: @Jalal - thanks, removed downvote accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like an IIS configuration problem. Have you made sure the App Pool is configured to `.NET 4.0`?

Comment: Yes, .NET version is 4.0.30319.1

Comment: Is your server a windows one? Or apache?

Comment: @csharpsi Apache can run on Windows, but the OP already tagged this question with IIS, which seems to answer the question you meant to ask, since IIS only runs on Windows.

Comment: @AndrewBarber bah! I'm blind. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewBarber PS. I meant linux. It's been a long monday... :)

Comment: @csharpsi Yup, that's the question I figured you meant to ask :)